# WildFly/Hibernate: update an embedded property failed

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly

Currently, I am trying to update the [eclipse-ee4j/cargotracker](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/cargotracker)(originally it is a rewritten version of the Eric's DDD book sample) to the latest Jakarta EE 8:

https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/tree/jakartaee8

Personally, I want to expand WildFly as an alternative application server. But I encountered several wired issues between Payara/ElipseLInks and WildFly/Hibernate.

There is a **[Cargo](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/blob/jakartaee8/src/main/java/org/eclipse/cargotracker/domain/model/cargo/Cargo.java)** entity that has a **[RouteSepcificaiton](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/blob/jakartaee8/src/main/java/org/eclipse/cargotracker/domain/model/cargo/RouteSpecification.java)** embeddable property that has departure and arrival **[Location](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/blob/jakartaee8/src/main/java/org/eclipse/cargotracker/domain/model/location/Location.java)**(Entity) and arrival deadline date.

Dummy code fragments of the relations:

```java
@Entity class Cargo{
    @Embedded routeSepcification;
}

@Embedable class RouteSpecificition{
    @ManyToOne Location origin
    @ManyToOne Location destination
}
@Entity class Location{}
```

The book new cargo works well, but when I want to change to the new route using `cargo.specifyNewRoute`, in another word, to update the route specification, it is not updated as expected.

The complete test code is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/blob/jakartaee8/src/test/java/org/eclipse/cargotracker/infrastructure/persistence/jpa/CargoRepositoryTest.java#L241).

```java
startTransaction();
        var trackingId = new TrackingId("AAA");
        Cargo cargo = cargoRepository.find(trackingId);

        assertThat(cargo).isNotNull();

        Location origin = locationRepository.find(SampleLocations.NEWYORK.getUnLocode());
        Location destination = locationRepository.find(SampleLocations.HELSINKI.getUnLocode());

        cargo.specifyNewRoute(new RouteSpecification(origin, destination, LocalDate.now()));

        cargoRepository.store(cargo);
        commitTransaction();

        //verify in the new tx
        startTransaction();
        var result = this.entityManager.createQuery("select c from Cargo c where c.trackingId=:trackingId", Cargo.class)
                .setParameter("trackingId", trackingId)
                .getSingleResult();

        assertThat(result.getTrackingId()).isEqualTo(trackingId);
        assertThat(result.getRouteSpecification().getOrigin()).isEqualTo(origin);
        assertThat(result.getRouteSpecification().getDestination()).isEqualTo(destination);
        assertThat(result.getItinerary().getLegs()).hasSize(1);

        commitTransaction();
```

The Arquillian test is failed on WildFly/Hibernate but **passed** on Payara/EclipseLinks.

Answer (score 0):

have you implemented the `equals` method for the `Location` entity?

If not I think the tests fails because the `EntityManager` used to retrieve the `origin` and `destination` and then to update the `Cargo` is not the same used in the second transaction block when you try to retrieve the updated `Cargo`, for this reason two new instances of the `destination` and `origin` Location are created by the second `EntityManager`.